# insert parentheses to series question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

i want to prove that if i have convergent series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_n$, so $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_n$ $\rightarrow S$, any series that becomes from inserting brackets to $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_n$ also converges to $S$.

How to start? by look on the partial sums sequence? can anyone show me a beautiful proof for this?

Comment: A single pair of brackets? Then after a while partial sums are the same.

Comment: @AndréNicolas oh no..i'll edit